# Unmarshaling JSON into struct but converting values into required dtypes

Tags: json, rest, http, go

I am using a JSON API for which I have to parse it into a struct. However, the API returns all values, even numbers, as strings and I need them to be in the format of numbers. So currently, I have a struct which has member fields which are all strings and after I have parsed the data, I loop through the entries to convert the values and add them to a new struct which has the specific entries in float or int values.

Is there any way to do the parsing and do type conversion in one go without having to use an intermediary struct representation from which to convert the values into the desired data types?

**Example Code**

```
str := []byte(`
{
    "name": "Jim Burnham",
    "age": "34",
    "dob_day": "22",
    "dob_month": "3",
    "dob_year": "1984"
}
`)
```

Here is a sample JSON declaration of a response from an API. Notice how the age, day, month and year are returned as strings rather than integers. Now I declare a struct with the desired fields with JSON tags to map the values correctly:

```
type person struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Age    int `json:"age"`
    DobDay int `json:"dob_day"`
    DobMonth int `json:"dob_month"`
    DobYear int `json:"dob_year"`
}
```

Then I declare an instance of the `person` struct and use the `json` package to unmarshal it into the instance of the struct:

```
var p person
_ = json.Unmarshal(str, &p)
fmt.Println(p)
```

But when I print out the person, the following output is generated:

```
{Jim Burnham 0 0 0 0}
```

As you can see, the string has been parsed correctly but the other integer fields remain at their default Golang initialized value. However, when I change the struct definition to :

```
type person struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Age    string `json:"age"`
    DobDay string `json:"dob_day"`
    DobMonth string `json:"dob_month"`
    DobYear string `json:"dob_year"`
}
```

I get the following output:

```
{Jim Burnham 34 22 3 1984}
```

This means that currently, I have to define a raw struct which parses the information in the format of a string but then define another struct with the desired dtypes and reassign and convert the values separately, which produces untidy code as well. However, this is just one case but in my use case, there are likely thousands or even sometimes millions of such values and it seems to be inefficient, even for a compiled language. This is why I am asking for solutions for such a problem.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/klHYlMQyb_V

Comment: ... for more complex cases you can declare a custom type and have it implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

Comment: That works so well. Thank you very much. It is neater than json.Number which someone else suggested.

Comment: You should post this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained well by @mkopriva at this link: https://play.golang.org/p/klHYlMQyb_V